# Sufficient conditions on $F$ such that $F(X)\in\mathcal{L}^{p}$ for all $X\in\mathcal{L}^{p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{L}^{p}$ the space of real-valued random variables with finite $p$-th moment ($p\in[1,\infty]$). Moreover, let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be measurable.

> What are sufficient conditions on $F$, such that $X\in\mathcal{L}^{p}\Rightarrow F(X)\in\mathcal{L}^{p}$ ?

Example: *F is bounded*. Then $F(X)\in\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ and thereby also $F(X)\in\mathcal{L}^{p}$.

Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Isn't the identity function an unbounded example?

Comment: That's correct. Boundedness is merely a sufficient condition, but not necessary. Can you think of any other sufficient condition?

Comment: @Mark $L^p$ of what? Your thoughts that a bounded function is in $L^p$ suggest you mean a finite measure, but is this is any finite measure space or the unit interval with Lebesgue? As it stands the question is too broad anyway, you should add more details for what motivates this question.

Comment: @3-in-441 Thanks for your comment. I added some details.

Comment: @3-in-441: It really doesn't matter what the measure space is, provided it's finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the usual condition to require would be *linear growth*: there exists a constant $C$ such that $|F(t)| \le C(1+|t|)$.  Suppose so; then if $X \in L^p$ we can write
$$\|F(X)\|_p \le C \|(1 + |X|)\|_p \le C(1 + \|X\|_p) < \infty$$
using Minkowski's inequality.

I suspect that in general this is necessary and sufficient, though I don't offhand know how to prove that.

Note that any Lipschitz function satisfies this; in particular, any differentiable function with bounded derivative.

For a space with infinite measure, you have to drop the 1 and require $|F(t)| \le C|t|$.  This is satisfied by any Lipschitz function with $F(0)=0$.

Comment: I asked about the converse [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625476/if-a-function-preserves-integrability-must-it-have-linear-growth).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!